# Version of installed software from remote computer registry using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, registry

I am trying to get the version of Installed software from the registry of the remote computer. Key of installed software is like

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\02A53310C105F76619D754734328A18F**

I also tried EXEC master..xp_regread in SQL server but using this we cannot read registry on a remote computer.

Comment: Are you trying to find the version of SQL Server or other software on Windows?

Comment: @SQL_Underworld Sorry for late reply. I am trying to get the version of other software on the remote computer from the registry.